Can we use sessionAttributes as inputTranscript in Lex V2?
So, I am working on IVR flow on Amazon Connect and Amazon Lex, in Amazon Connect I am storing customer's initial input to a contact attribute with a key "user_input". In Get Customer input block I am passing that user_input as a session attribute, now in Lex V2 I want to use that user_input as a session attribute and automatically detect the intent (there are 25 intents in a bot) and starts the conversation.
We can achieve this by using Lambda function, but we are planning not to use it. I just want to know is there a way for this.

Yep, you can use Amazon Lex V2 to figure out the intent based on the session attribute. Just make sure your Lex bot is set up to use the "user_input" session attribute correctly. In Lex V2, you can configure a slot or an initial prompt to work with this session attribute, which helps Lex figure out the intent automatically. Just double-check that the session attribute is passed from Amazon Connect and is correctly mapped in Lex.
